# Unable to get temporary credentials for Amazon Dynamodb access using Google Login in Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I received the token from Google but not able to get the required aws credentials using WebIdentityFederationSessionCredentialsProvider in Android.(Getting error:Unable to load AWS Credentials from any provider in the chain).Need help.

Code Used is given below

```
    public void login( WIFIdentityProvider wifIDP, final AlertActivity activity ) {
    idp = wifIDP;
    AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient sts=new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient();
    sts.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));             
    wif = new WebIdentityFederationSessionCredentialsProvider(idp.getToken(),idp.getProviderID(),idp.getRoleARN(),sts); 
    //call refresh to login from an AsyncTask because refreshing requires the network

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Throwable>() {
        @Override
        protected Throwable doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            try {
                wif.refresh();////ERROR RECEIVED AT THIS POINT
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.d("buzz","Err:"+t);
                return t;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Throwable t) {
            if (t != null) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unable to login.", t);
                activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

            } else {
                ddb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient( wif );
                ddb.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
                AmazonSharedPreferencesWrapper.storeUsername(sharedPreferences, wif.getSubjectFromWIF());
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Logged in with user id " + wif.getSubjectFromWIF());
                activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
            }
            activity.finish();
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: At what point do you receive this message? You fail to show this provider being used for any service calls.  Additionally, it is unnecessary to set the region on the STS client as [STS only has one endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#sts_region).  You can simply use the WebIdentityFederationSessionCredentialsProvider that takes the 3 required arguments.

Comment: Thanks Bob Kinney for the reply.I did set the region because I actually read from aws documentation that by default, region is set to us-east-1.Without adding sts, I was getting an error Access Denied. ERROR RECEIVED : com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: AWSSecurityTokenService, AWS Request ID: dfd07030-7821-11e3-821f-6b1986d78b19, AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, AWS Error Message: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, STS is not available in US_WEST_2, so I would recommend removing this line.

The "Not authorized" error you mentioned in your reply comment usually indicates that you may have incorrectly entered your application ID when configuring your IAM role for web identity federation.  Can you confirm that you entered the client ID from the [Google API Console](https://developers.google.com/console)?

Comment: Yes.I have entered ClientId from Google API Console.I have also created an Auth2.0 ClientId for the Android Application.I am using the ClientId that was generated for my project.(*************.apps.googleusercontent.com).As mentioned I have removed STS line.But getting Error as I mentioned.(Access Denied).